# How to get rid of advertisements?

Tags: discussion, advice

I am really fond of the advertisements by math.se site itself, it always leads to amazing places on net, such as MIT OCW, KHAN ACADEMY, Inverse calculator, English and Crypto Q&A, Geogebra, AMS Grad blog etc.,just to name a few. I have got too much with these ad.s and so I should thank such advertises and their advertisers.

My anger is against the "Ad.s not by this site". Let me show some examples:
[image]

I am offered car accessories and bank loans.Sometimes I have to guess "her" age![image]

Once I was offered a "trick" to make my wife "happy" that night, although I am not married.

I had no problem earlier with these ad.s but now I have got to know that these are data-consuming. They do not allow me to concentrate on math.

I will be obliged if I am offered some advice to get rid of them.

Comment: Have you checked your computer for viruses/malware recently?

Comment: @ArthurFischer, no but I purchased laptop just 3 months ago.

Comment: Well, 3 months is quite  enough time to get infected with such things. The ads you are seeing do not come from this site; they come from some program  on your computer that inserts them. Nothing we can help with. Other than recommend the SE site [Super User](http://superuser.com) for general computer-related issues...

Comment: I see no ads on [that question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/586823/8348) like you do ([very recent screenshot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/XZIVB.png)).  It is almost certainly some malware (adware) on your computer that is parsing the page and adding the adverts.

Comment: Not exactly the same, but a similar problem in an older post: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/11245/new-ads-on-mse

Comment: Congratulations. You have blindly installed something like that. Also 3 months is about a 100 times more than enough time to get such software installed.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are no ads at all on Math.SE (with the exception of inhouse ads for other sites, proposals and the community ads in the sidebar). This is the case for all SE sites with the exception of the trilogy sites Stack Overflow, Super User and Server Fault. Only those three sites have ads, but not inline ads as you describe them.

This is almost certainly caused by adware installed on your PC, or much less likely inserted by your internet provider on the fly.